# Tablet restarts when I launch app from Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, tablet

My tablet restars once in two or three times when I launch my app from Eclipse. Since nothing appears on Logcat or Error Log, I cannot post any clue. I just wonder what kind of codes can cause such behaviour, so I can check if I have written something wrong.
The problem is again, I launch my app on my tablet from Eclipse, then tablet just restarts instead of launching app. This happens once in every two or three launch. Has any of you encountered such a problem?

Comment: Yes saw that. A lot of devices did that once. But now i have on which does it 9/10. It's unusuable for development.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

clear log from device

```
adb logcat -c
```

run the app let tablet restart when back capture the log in text file and check whats happening.

```
adb shell logcat > log.txt
```

Comment: `first delete old log file from device`. Ok. What is the name of the file? And in which directory is it? Adb command for it?